# Is there any chance to install xfce on SLED 12SP3?

Tags: suse, xfce

I would like to customize interface but out of the box Gnome doesnt allow me to move panel even. So I want to install xfce but I cannot find such metapackage/template in repos.

Comment: Did you try it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is actually tricky question.  You want to install something that is not in the official repository but you still watn to get full support for your SLED.

It appears in the official repositories you can not install xfce.

The official documentation - [Deployment guide](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sled-12/pdfdoc/book_sle_deployment/book_sle_deployment.pdf) recommends using [packagehub](https://packagehub.suse.com/) as the source for SLED.  You still will get support your paid support if using these. However, Xfce is not there either. I would recommend going with KDE 4/5 or whatever you can find there as it has been tested for use with SLED. You can ask there if xfce can be added.

You can also search for your wished package via *[Find package for any supported SuSE](https://software.opensuse.org/find)* but for SLED 12SP3 you can find only these:

[xfce4-dev-tools](https://software.opensuse.org/package/xfce4-dev-tools)
[xfce4-splash-branding-openSUSE](https://software.opensuse.org/package/xfce4-splash-branding-openSUSE)

If you insist on using Xfce as your gui in SLED you have to build it yourself.

I recommend using [Administration guide](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles-12/pdfdoc/book_sle_admin/book_sle_admin.pdf) from SuSE

> 6.2.6 Compiling RPM Packages with build

In general you will be creating a defined *build* environment for wished xfce.  I don't know if it is worth it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @tukan, appreciate it. True, there is no way to install xfce from official repos. I had deiceded to move to kde which is highly customizable but...after install I hadnt managed to get my wireless working (despite it worked fine in gnome sled before).  Definitely, SLED is a stable (thats what I like), good and mature distro, but it does not make any sense to use it without paying to support or to try to use it as home distro. Switched to Fedora and am enjoying now.

Comment: @sky: weird, that should not be problem with NetworkManager. Which KDE did you install? Anyways, if you like Fedora you may try OpenSuSE leap(distro based) or tumbleweed(rolling diatro). OpenSuSE is to SLED as Fedora is to RedHat Enterprise linux.